# UK Limited company - confusion around National insurance thresholds and Employee Personnal allowance

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, self-employment

I could not find answers to my question online, so I thought someone here might know what can be done regarding the below:

I have a standard limited company with a 1185L tax code.

Looking at: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/rates-and-thresholds-for-employers-2018-to-2019

- I see that my "Employee personal allowance" is of £11,500 for 2018-2019.
- I also see that the National Insurance thresholds is of: £8,424.

So, assuming I have been paying me 8,424/12 = £702 each month (I submitted FPS using HMRC Basic Paye Tool to do so), amount my former accountant suggested me to pay myself, how can I close the £11,500* - £8,424 = £3,076 gap? Also will I have to pay National Insurance taxes on this £3,076 notional?

Thanks. :)

*(or even £11,850 if I do understand my tax properly)

Comment: Why do you want, or believe you _need_ to "close the gap"? As I understand it (but IANAA), on £8,424 you pay neither income tax nor NI contributions (either as an employee or employer). If you paid yourself £11,850, there still would be no income tax, but there would be NI to pay (if I read it correctly, 12% and 13.8% of £3,426). What I don't know is if/how not earning enough to pay NI will affect things like the state pension.

Comment: @TripeHound Thank you for your anwser. I was just trying to reproduce what my accountant had me do in the first. Somehow I understood I was not paying anything on the "gap" which seemed odd as you highlighted.

Comment: Note that NI is charged on a per-pay-period basis, and employee NI has an upper limit beyond which NI drops off significantly. Therefore a better option than 11500/12 = 958 per month would be 8424/12 = 702 per month for 11 months, and 11500-702*11 = 3778 in the 12th month. Whether this is better than 702 per month as salary and the rest of dividends, I have no idea (I don't own a company).